# How to Add Text and Formatting to Cells in Word Tables?

Tags: c#

I want add from **data grid** a lot of data to word table.

How add data to **word table**?

Comment: What is your question ??

Comment: Are you talking about creating a document in Microsoft Word from C#?  What do you mean by "word table"?

Comment: Prasad Kanaparthi: I want some data from data grid read and write to Microsoft Word table.